# Is there a way for MockedStatic to return a mocked class?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am trying using Junit's MockedStatic function for Hadoop FileSystem class static method "get()" and want to return a mocked Hadoop FileSystem which then I will use Mockito for its other methods such as "exists()". However, when I tried debugging it, the MockedStatic didnt return a mocked FileSystem class but an actual one.

```
public class ClassA{
     public void methodA (String input){
          //some code
          FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(pathName), configuration);
          boolean fileExists = fileSystem.exists(new Path(fileName));
          //some code
     }
}

class ClassATest{

@Mock
FileSystem fileSystem;
@InjectMocks
ClassA classA;

@BeforeEach
void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
void methodA {
    try (MockedStatic<FileSystem> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(FileSystem.class)){
            mockedStatic.when(()-> 
    FileSystem.get(URI.create("/resources/"),configuration)).thenReturn(fileSystem);
        }
    when(fileSystem.exists(any())).thenReturn(true);
}
```

Comment: You don't even call `ClassA.methodA` in your test

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you must use (JUnit 4):

- `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` class decoration, or
- call `Mockito.initMocks(this)` in your setup method, to initialize these mocks and inject them.

With JUnit 5, you must use:

- `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` class decoration.